# Iterate through JSON String and get Key and Value Both

Tags: java, json

I have this String that I want to Iterate Through:

{"First Name":"John","Last Name":"Doe"}

I want the Key and Value Both as the Keys can change and will be dynamic.

I have tried many ways to iterate and get all the keys and values but in vain.

Comment: "I have tried many ways to iterate" - which exactly? We need to know to suggest solutions you haven't tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jackson library to convert your string to a map:

```
        final String jsonString = "{\"First Name\":\"John\",\"Last Name\":\"Doe\"}\"";
        final Map<String, Object> jsonObject = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
```

Then you can easily iterate over keys and their values.

Answer (score 0):

One of many options is to use `Gson` with a `TypeAdapter` and allow what I assume is a `Person` object to be encoded and decoded with dynamic keys.

```java
    static class Person {

        private final String firstName;

        private final String lastName;

        Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
    }
```

```java
   static class PersonTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Person> {

        private final String firstNameKey;

        private final String lastNameKey;

        PersonTypeAdapter(String firstNameKey, String lastNameKey) {
            this.firstNameKey = firstNameKey;
            this.lastNameKey = lastNameKey;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, Person value) throws IOException {
            out.beginObject()
                    .name(firstNameKey).value(value.firstName)
                    .name(lastNameKey).value(value.lastName)
                    .endObject();
        }

        @Override
        public Person read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            in.beginObject();

            String firstNameValue = null;

            String lastNameValue = null;

            while (in.hasNext()) {
                String key = in.nextName();

                if (key.equals(firstNameKey)) {
                    firstNameValue = in.nextString();
                } else if (key.equals(lastNameKey)) {
                    lastNameValue = in.nextString();
                } else {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported key.");
                }
            }
            in.endObject();

            if (firstNameValue == null || lastNameValue == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("First name or last name is null.");
            }

            return new Person(firstNameValue, lastNameValue);
        }
    }
```

```java
        String json = "{\"First Name\":\"John\",\"Last Name\":\"Doe\"}\n" +
                "\n";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Person.class, new PersonTypeAdapter("First Name", "Last Name"))
                .create();

        Person person = gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
```

```
Json result: com.Solution$Person@5f4da5c3[firstName=John,lastName=Doe]
```

Comment: Thanks Everyone. Jackson Library did the Magic.